# Закрыть соединение в библиотеке Ratchet WebSockets

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

Я использую для работы WebSockets, библиотеку [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) 
Обратил внимание что в данной библиотеке не происходит автоматического закрывания не активного соединения, которое требуется закрыть.

Например у меня есть соединение #101, по некоторым причинам устройство закрывает соединение с сервером (отключился интернет), и через какое-то время устройство подключается вновь к серверу, тем самым открывая новое соединение но уже #102, при этом соединение #101 продолжает работать.

Сервер отправляет некую команду на устройство но так как несколько соединений - команда не долетает, по итогу создается множество не активных соединений которые грузят сервер и все не работает должным образом.

Кто сталкивался с подобным явлением?

Comment: Периодически отправляйте "ping" клиентам, если клиент не отвечает, то закрывайте соединение

Comment: Понятное дело) В Ratchet что бы отправить команду к устройству нужно выполнить loop, т,е мы уже будем не находится в зоне выполнения основного класса и в loop каждое соединение нужно перебирать в ручную. Например 100 устройств и сколько же ложных, loop весь сервак повесит если это делать например с периодичностью хотя бы 30 секунд.

Comment: делайте с периодичностью 300 секунд. Выставите таймаут в 1 секунду. Не отправляйте пинг, если клиент получал или отправлял сообщение в последние 300 секунд